# Re-render jQuery select control after refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have managed to tweak the jQuery SELECT controls visually just abit...problem is if on any other page the user hits f5 or refresh and returns to this home page all but the *last* select is rendered blank?!?!

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforeshow", "#home", function() {
  $("select.listings option[value='']").each(function() {

      // NOTE: This produces weird results?!?!
      var elm = $(this).parent().prev();
      console.log(elm.html());
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML? Without it is a vague question.

Comment: its just <select> but its wrapped by jQM with a DIV to stylize the control?

Comment: Without your code there is no way we would know why your last `select` is rendered blank.

Comment: Is there a link, at least?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no HTML or link to troubleshoot with, I'll shoot from the hip here:

Wouldn't this syntax be more current:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function() {
  var elm = $(this).parent().prev();

  var txt  = $(this).text();
  var tmp = txt.replace("(", "<br /><small style='color: #aeaeae'>").replace(")", "</small>");

  elm.html(tmp);
}
```

I'm going to assume your html selects have options like:

```
<select class="listings">
  <option value="">(label) text</option>
  <option value="">(label) text</option>
</select>
```

My test link can be viewed at http://www.donboots.com/pagebeforeshow.html. I didn't use jsfiddle since they may have some anti-caching going on.

Comment: OK...maybe what the issue was/is (kinda)...the event handler "pagebeforeshow" fires for each page but the 'this' context changes when refresh is pressed so the $(this).parent().prev() -- when I dump this to console.log() the change is obvious (bug?) I just don't know how to work around it or fix it